# Spring integration tcp connection send, receive data and shutdown by request

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm developing a spring web application. I want to use tcp connection in spring integration to communicate with PABX where:
1. I can send or receive data anytime I want as long as the connection had not terminated.
2. I can start or terminate the connection anytime I want.

Is it possible if I use spring integration? Is there any sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html); there are a number of sample apps in the [sample repostitory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) - a couple in the `basic` directory and another under `intermediate`.